# class based views -TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type

Tags: python, django, super, django-class-based-views

I am building an app in Django, it uses class based views.

In my views.py I have this class based view that allows to inspect details of objects in my model `Product`:

```
class ProductDetailView(DetailView):
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    template_name = "products/detail.html"

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(ProductListView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        return context
```

As I try to run the server I get this traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
context = super(ProductListView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you derived yourself, the type should be an element of the [Method Resolution Order (MRO)](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/method-resolution-order-in-python-inheritance/) of `self`, so:

```
class ProductDetailView(DetailView):
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    template_name = 'products/detail.html'

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(ProductDetailView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        return context
```

however, since [python-3.x](/questions/tagged/python-3.x), you do *not* need to pass parameter to `super()`: If you are using the class where it is defined, and `self` as parameter, you can make use of `super()`, so you can rewrite this to:

```
class ProductDetailView(DetailView):
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    template_name = 'products/detail.html'

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        return context
```

This thus makes it easy to define a code fragment that can be easily copy pasted to other views.

Furthermore here it makes no sense to override `get_context_data`, since you only call the super method and return its result, you can ommit the override.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED

The traceback says

> obj must be an instance or subtype of type

pointing at `super(type, obj)`

This means that the second argument that you pass to super must be an instance or subtype of the first one.

If you look at your code, `ProductListView` is not an instance or subtype of `self`, that in the case is equal to `ProductDetailView`.

This is obviously a bad copy-paste issue. Replace

```
context = super(ProductListView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
```

with

```
context = super(ProductDetailView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
```